# Why is my Electron Cash not detecting any servers?

Tags: synchronization, peer-discovery, electron-cash

I am using Elecron Cash 2.9.4, and I opened the wallet by using the seed of my old (BTC) Electrum Wallet. I intended to get BCH.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Solved! It automatically tarted detecting after an hour or so, but one of the things I tried might have worked - updated Electron Cash, and restarted the Wifi.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. The solution is easy.[image]

Choose the "Server" tab, then randomly right click on a server and choose "Use this as server"

[image]

To make sure it works properly, please choose one of these: https://github.com/fyookball/electrum/blob/b32f10a/lib/network.py#L54-L58

I've [reported the bug](https://github.com/fyookball/electrum/issues/268) to Electron Cash' developer. Thank you for noticing it!

Answer (score -2):

Try to update your Electron wallet in playstore. Be sure you're connected and have strong enough data or signal. Be sure it's not counterfeit, Lmo!!