# Bitcoins didn't arrived

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

3-4 days ago, I transferred bitcoins from Virwox to my Electrum wallet, but this bitcoins didn't arrived, what can i do?
1JPSVx7hjcu7rR2Vr6nyz7z8mok3yryGZ

Comment: Do you see a green dot in the bottom-right corner of Electrum, showing that it's synced?

Comment: No, i got red dot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Electron Cash not detecting any servers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62926/why-is-my-electron-cash-not-detecting-any-servers)

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, you're coins are safe. You only need to fix the connection. You should go to *Tools* -> *Network* and then choose a server.

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved! If you could click on the ✔️ button, that'd be great as it shows others that my solution worked for you.